# Handing a pointer over to another function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I'm having trouble with this code. When I execute "PrepareEncryption" (in example), the code returns a valid pointer, but when I pass it on to "EncryptBig" it isn't valid no more (points to random numbers). My best bet is that the original struct is deleted. So how do I preserve it, if that's the problem? And I know that there is a memory leak btw.

```
struct filecrypt
{
    FILE* bestand;
    FILE* nieuwbstnd;
    unsigned int positie;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int huidig;
    float procentum;
};

struct filecrypt *PrepareEncryption(char* locatie)
{
    struct stat file_status;
    struct filecrypt origineel, *mirror;
    int error;
    char* nieuw;

    if (stat(locatie, &file_status) != 0)
        return NULL;

    error = fopen_s(&origineel.bestand, locatie, "rb");
    if (error != 0)
        return NULL;

    error = strlen(locatie)+5;
    nieuw = (char*)malloc(error);
    if (nieuw == NULL)
        return NULL;
    strcpy_s(nieuw, error-3, locatie);
    strcat_s(nieuw, error, ".cpt");

    error = fopen_s(&origineel.nieuwbstnd, nieuw, "wb+");
    if (error != 0)
        return NULL;

    origineel.huidig = 0;
    origineel.positie = 0;
    origineel.procentum = 0.0f;
    origineel.size = file_status.st_size;
    mirror = &origineel;
    return mirror;
}

float EncryptBig(struct filecrypt *handle)
{
    int i, index = 0;
    float calc;
    char buf, *bytes = (char*)malloc(10485760); // 10 MB
    if (bytes == NULL)
    {
        handle = NULL;
        fcloseall();
        return -1.0f;
    }

    for (i = handle->huidig; i < (handle->huidig+10485760); i++)
    {
        if (i > handle->size)
            break;

        fseek(handle->bestand, i, SEEK_SET);
        fread_s(&buf, 1, 1, 1, handle->bestand);

        __asm
        {
            mov         eax, dword ptr [bytes]  
            add         eax, dword ptr [index]  
            mov         cl, byte ptr [buf]
            xor         cl, 18
            xor         cl, 75
            not         cl
            mov         byte ptr [eax], cl 
            mov         eax, dword ptr [index]  
            add         eax, 1  
            mov         dword ptr [index], eax
        }
    }

    fwrite(bytes, 1, i, handle->nieuwbstnd);
    fseek(handle->nieuwbstnd, i, SEEK_SET);

    handle->huidig += i;
    calc = (float)handle->huidig;
    calc /= (float)handle->size;
    calc *= 100.0f;

    if (calc == 100.0)
    {
        // GEHEUGEN LEK!
        // MOET NOG BIJGEWERKT WORDEN!
        fcloseall();
        handle = NULL;
    }
    return calc;
}

void example(char* path)
{
    float progress;
    struct filecrypt* handle;

    handle = PrepareEncryption(path);
    do
    {
        progress = EncryptBig(handle);
        printf_s("%f", progress);
    }
    while (handle != NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you return a pointer to a local variable.

Local variables are stored on the stack, and when a function returns that area of the stack is reused by other functions, and you are left with a pointer that now points to unused memory or memory now occupied by something else. This is *undefined behaviour*, and might sometimes work, might sometimes give you "garbage" data, and may sometimes crash.

Answer (score 0):

In PrepareEncryption you are returning pointer to `struct filecrypt origineel`, which is allocated on stack (local object). This is the problem. Just after the function returns (ends its execution) the memory occupied by `origineel` becomes invalid. You need to allocate it on the heap, by a call to malloc.

Answer (score 0):

You do:

```
mirror = &origineel;
return mirror;
```

`origineel` is a local variable. The above is equivalent to:

```
return &origineel;
```

...you're returning a pointer to a local variable, that goes out of scope at the end of the function. The fact that it appears to sometimes return a valid pointer is just chance.

Use `malloc`, or better yet, pass the pointer address to the target location as an argument to your function and don't return it:

```
int *PrepareEncryption(struct filecrypt *origineel, char* locatie);

struct filecrypt myStruct;
PrepareEncryption(&myStruct, "abc");
```